# Android telegram Compile failed，Powerless

Tags: android, android-ndk, telegram

The ndk version I use is 20.1.5948944.as version is 3.5.
error hint:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:externalNativeBuildAfatDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process D:\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.1.5948944\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=G:\project\proj\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=G:\project\proj\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=G:/project/proj/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/afatDebug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=G:\project\proj\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\afatDebug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 tmessages.30}
  Android NDK: WARNING:G:/project/proj/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni/libtgvoip/Android.mk:flac: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
  Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in G:/project/proj/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni/libtgvoip/Android.mk for module flac    
  Android NDK:   ./exoplayer/libFLAC/windows_unicode_filenames    
  [arm64-v8a] StaticLibrary  : libcrypto_arm64-v8a.a
.......
  make: *** [G:/project/proj/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/afatDebug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libcrypto_arm64-v8a.a] Error 87
```

[image: full error]

The code exceeds the 3000 limit, so a part is omitted!
I need your help!

Comment: Can we at least see your `jni/libtgvoip/Android.mk` file? We cannot do much with the error message alone.

Comment: @Botje thanks,I modified the MK file and solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
First line add:
`LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS := true`

TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk
First line add:
`APP_SHORT_COMMANDS := true`